# Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost

Tags: spring, eclipse, tomcat

Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost.
Multiple Contexts have a path of "/SpringMVC".

my application is springMVC_crud but it is catching previous application server . while creating springMVC_crud I dragged all my MVC and web.xml file and jsp also but changed all the things where required.But still it is showing same?